# ApolloClient Typescript Higher Order Component issue (not assignable to type)

Tags: typescript, react-native, apollo-client

I'm trying to create a HOC in a React Native app, but I'm having issues getting the definitions to work.

```
interface IWithApolloClientComponentProps {
    apolloClient: ApolloClient<any>;
}
export function withApolloClient<
    P extends IWithApolloClientComponentProps, 
    R = Omit<P, keyof IWithApolloClientComponentProps>
>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentType<R> {
        return function BoundComponent(props: R) {
            return <ApolloConsumer>{client => <Component {...props} apolloClient={client} />} . 
        </ApolloConsumer>;
    };
}
```

My VSCode keeps giving the following error:

```
Type 'R & { apolloClient: ApolloClient<object>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'R & { apolloClient: ApolloClient<object>; }' is not assignable to type 'P'.
'R & { apolloClient: ApolloClient<object>; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IWithApolloClientComponentProps'.ts(2322)
```

Is anyone seeing something I'm doing terribly wrong here?

Comment: Does HOC stand for "high order calculator" or something else?

Comment: HOC is a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are *almost* there.  The generic `R = Omit<P, keyof IWithApolloClientComponentProps>` means that `R` can be set to anything, but will default to `Omit<P, keyof IWithApolloClientComponentProps>`.  We don't want this to be a generic -- it should always have that same `Omit` value.

If we try this:

```
export function withApolloClient<P extends IWithApolloClientComponentProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.ComponentType<Omit<P, keyof IWithApolloClientComponentProps>> {
  return function BoundComponent(
    props: Omit<P, keyof IWithApolloClientComponentProps>
  ) {
    return (
      <ApolloConsumer>
        {(client) => <Component {...props} apolloClient={client} />}
      </ApolloConsumer>
    );
  };
}
```

it's better, but we still get an error:

> 'Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "apolloClient">> & { apolloClient: ApolloClient; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IWithApolloClientComponentProps'

Comparing those two types, we dropped the key `"apolloClient"` from `P` and then added  the prop `ApolloClient<object>` to that same key.  So basically the only way it's not assignable is if `P` required a specific type of `ApolloClient` which was not `<object>`.

Knowing that, you might feel comfortable to assert `{...props as P}`.

There is another way which doesn't require an `as` assertions.  Instead of `P` referring to all props including `IWithApolloClientComponentProps`, we use `P` to describe just the other props.

```
export function withApolloClient<P extends object>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P & IWithApolloClientComponentProps>
): React.ComponentType<P> {
  return function BoundComponent(props: P) {
    return (
      <ApolloConsumer>
        {(client) => <Component {...props} apolloClient={client} />}
      </ApolloConsumer>
    );
  };
}
```

There is no error here because our inner component takes client type `ApolloClient<any>`.